# How I remove or erase ls -l | head -3 | tail -l to start over. What command I type?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, shell

How do I remove or erase

```
ls -l | head -3 | tail -l
```

to start over. What command should I use?

Since my `ls -l | head -3 | tail - l` has double `exit1.sh`, `exit2.sh.it` isn’t same picture instruction

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Double exit? What do you mean by that? To start over, you would do _Ctrl-C_ and then restart the command (arrow up + enter).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't understand your question.  If you want a new connamd in the shell, just type the new command. If you want to clear the screen, type `clear`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `tail -l`? Maybe you want to use `tail -1`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't - the output of that command appears to simply show the last 3 lines of a file listing (the -l should likely be -1 to show the last line, it is a pointless command as written)

You can simply type the next command and it should work.

If you have a display problem with your terminal, or just want to clear the screen, type the below command (even if you can't see what you are typing for some reason)

> reset [enter]

This will clear the screen and try and resize/reset the terminal.